# React navigation tab too big on small screens

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a bottom tab in React Native with React Navigation It works perfectly on 2160x1080 and 1920×1080 screens but when I try the app on a 480x800 or smaller screens I get a stretched bottom Tab.

[image: as shown in this image]

This is my code:

Tab stack

```
<TabStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
    <TabStack.Screen
      name="Bills"
      component={BillsScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
          <Icon name="cash-multiple" color={color} size={30} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <TabStack.Screen
      name="Loans"
      component={LoansScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
          <Icon name="restore-clock" color={color} size={30} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <TabStack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
          <Icon name="home-outline" color={color} size={30} />
        ),
      }}
    />
   ...
  </TabStack.Navigator>
```

Home stack:

```
 <HomeStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Tab" screenOptions={screenOptions}>
    <HomeStack.Screen
      name="Tab"
      component={CreateTabStack}
      options={{headerShown: false}}
    />
    <HomeStack.Screen name="Invest" component={InvestScreen} />
    <HomeStack.Screen
      name="Pay"
      component={PaymentScreen}
      options={{headerShown: false}}
    />
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
```

Root stack:

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
        {user ? (
          <RootStack.Screen name="HomeStack" component={CreateHomeStack} />
        ) : (
          <RootStack.Screen name="AuthStack" component={CreateAuthStack} />
        )}
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Did you try to decrease your size?  <Icon name="cash-multiple" color={color} size={20}/>

Answer (score 1):

```
//Calculate windowHeight Dimention to make sure its the same ratio
//everywhere
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

//Call to set dynamic height change of tabBar using ratio 
tabBarOptions={style:{height:windowHeight/someNum}}
```

`someNum` can be whichever value you decide on.

That will be a dynamic approach and will have the same behavior on all different screens.

you can even log the height in where it fits perfect and use that value by dividing over the `windowHeight` to get the ratio to use in `someNum`.